# problems using getchar() and buffer issues

Tags: c, loops, input, buffer, getchar

I think I'm correct to say that this code is having some kind of ***buffer*** issue.
If I use `fflush(stdin);`, the code works as desired.

How do these buffers work? Is it better to use `getche()` or `getch()` including `<conio.h>` instead of using `getchar()` ?
In this code, I can't print "Stack Overflow" more than two times.
Thanks for your help in advance :), have a great day!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  char ch;
  do{
        printf("Stack Overflow\n");
        printf("print again? (y/n)"); 
        // fflush(stdin);
    ch = getchar();
    }while(ch == 'y');

  printf("Done\n");
}
```

Comment: There are no ***buffer*** issues. The issue is that `getchar` will read the `\n` - newline character that is fed by the Enter key after your `'y'`. So you might want to skip/ignore any newline/whitespace characters (or any non-`'y/n'` character).

Comment: `fflush()` on an input stream is undefined and shouldn't be used.

Comment: `char ch;` --> `int ch;` because `getchar` can return `EOF`. `fflush` of an _input_ stream is unsupported/UB. You might have better luck with `fgets`: `char ch; char buf[1000];  do { printf("Stack Overflow\n"); printf("print again? (y/n)"); if (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin) == NULL) break; ch = buf[0]; } while (ch == 'y');`

Comment: Is getchar() reading two characters 'y' and '\n' ? Is that why the loop exited in second iteration (where ch = '\n')? Why does re-prompting not work?